# Difference between `observeOn` and parametrized Scheduler

Tags: rxjs

I would expect the following two pieces of code to be equivalent. Repeat uses a `currentThread` scheduler by default. If we change it ti an `immediate` scheduler:

```
Rx.Observable.fromArray([1,2,3,4,5]).flatMap(a => {
  return Rx.Observable.repeat(a, 3, Rx.Scheduler.immediate)
})
.subscribe(r => console.log(r));
```

The code above produces the expected result: `1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, ...`. But the following code doesn't, and produces a sequence of mixed values:

```
Rx.Observable.fromArray([1,2,3,4,5]).flatMap(a => {
  return Rx.Observable.repeat(a, 3).observeOn(Rx.Scheduler.immediate)
})
.subscribe(r => console.log(r));
```

I don't understand this behavior, but I guess I am missing something. `repeat` can be passed a Scheduler parameter, but I thought I could also force the Observable on a particular Scheduler by using `observeOn`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that one is using the scheduler for generation, the second is just using it for propagation.

In the second version you are still using `currentThread` for the creation of the values. `observeOn` will only coerce values onto different schedulers *after they are emitted from the previous operator* but for operators that generate events this won't affect the generation of those events.

If you look inside of some of the creation operators (like `fromArray`) you'll see something like:

```
//Changing the scheduler will change how recursive scheduling works
scheduler.schedulerRecursiveWithState(0, function(self, state) {
      if (i < len) {
        observer.onNext(array[i]);
        //Schedule the next event
        self(i + 1);
      } else {
        observer.onCompleted();
      }
});
```

whereas `observeOn` is akin to doing something like:

```
//Doesn't change when events get generated, simply reschedules them for down stream
source.subscribe(function(x) {
  scheduler.scheduleWithState(x, function(self, state) {
    observer.onNext(x);
  });
});
```

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying. In that case, using `observeOn` for an operator like `repeat` is *never* useful, correct?

Comment: I don't know that I would go so far as to say *never*.  Certainly, it is difficult to see use cases for switching between `currentThread` and `immediate` but there might be cases where you want to switch from `currentThread` to a `VirtualTimeScheduler` or between two `VirtualTimeScheduler`s who have different notions of `now`.